# Alternatives to multiplication/division/modulo for encoding choices?

Tags: data-compression

The obvious way to encode, with minimum entropy, choosing s out of n (equiprobable) choices when x is already encoded is to identify s with a number [0, n) and set x = n * x + s, decoded with s = x % n, x = x / n.

Is this optimal if the only constraint is that the encoded result must be a bitstring? Would *+/% still be the choice if they were not available as instructions?

I know arithmetic coding (and ANS) exists, but it also can't avoid big integer arithmetic without giving up some entropy.

Comment: Do you have a different set of allowed instructions in mind? In general, all we need is a bijection between $[n^m] \times [n]$ and $[n^{m+1}]$ for every natural $m$.

Comment: Not in particular, though basically I have bitwise logic in mind. TBH it's not obvious to me how to even convert a [n^(m+1)] into a bitstring without operations that amount to multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement ANS using only additions, masks and shifts. Take a look at [Finite State Entropy (FSE)](https://github.com/Cyan4973/FiniteStateEntropy), it's a performance-focused version of ANS with accurate compression.